# The class of models of the positive theory of fields

Tags: model-theory

Let $T$ be the deductive closure of the theory of fields in the signature $(+,-,*,0,1)$, and let $T'$ be the deductive closure of the positive formulas of $T$. Is it true that $Mod(T)$ is the class of fields united with the class of singleton rings? What, precisely, is the class of models of the positive theory of fields? Just to clarify, a positive formula is one built up from atomic formulas using disjunction, conjunction, universal quantifiers, and existential quantifiers.

Comment: Can you clarify what counts as a positive sentence for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lyndon's preservation theorem says that the positive formulas in your sense are exactly those preserved under quotients, aka surjective homomorphisms, aka homomorphic images. As a consequence, an elementary class of structures is closed under quotients if and only if it is axiomatized by a positive theory (see p. 67 of [these notes](http://www.personal.psu.edu/t20/notes/master.pdf)).

So the positive theory of fields has as its class of models the smallest elementary class containing the fields and closed under quotients. The image of a field $K$ under a ring homomorphism is still a ring, and if it is not isomorphic to $K$, then the kernel of the homomorphism must be the only other ideal in $K$, namely the unit ideal. So the class of quotients of fields is exactly the fields together with the trivial ring. This is already an elementary class, so it's $\text{Mod}(T')$, as you guessed.

Comment: Another simpler way to see this: "$0\not=1$" is the only non-positive axiom in the field axioms, and when we drop it we're left with two possibilities: $0\not=1$ (field) or $0=1$ (trivial ring).